# Python remove outliers from data

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a data frame as following:

```
ID Value
A   70
A   80
B   75
C   10
B   50
A   1000
C   60
B   2000
..  ..
```

I would like to group this data by ID, remove the outliers from the grouped data (the ones we see from the boxplot) and then calculate mean.

So far

```
grouped = df.groupby('ID')

statBefore = pd.DataFrame({'mean': grouped['Value'].mean(), 'median': grouped['Value'].median(), 'std' : grouped['Value'].std()})
```

**How can I find outliers, remove them and get the statistics.**

Comment: This is essentially a duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686720/is-there-a-numpy-builtin-to-reject-outliers-from-a-list/45215127#45215127, with a few answers already

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a numpy builtin to reject outliers from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686720/is-there-a-numpy-builtin-to-reject-outliers-from-a-list)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the method you're referring to is to remove values > 1.5 * the interquartile range away from the median. So first, calculate your initial statistics:

```
statBefore = pd.DataFrame({'q1': grouped['Value'].quantile(.25), \
'median': grouped['Value'].median(), 'q3' : grouped['Value'].quantile(.75)})
```

And then determine whether values in the original DF are outliers:

```
def is_outlier(row):
    iq_range = statBefore.loc[row.ID]['q3'] - statBefore.loc[row.ID]['q1']
    median = statBefore.loc[row.ID]['median']
    if row.Value > (median + (1.5* iq_range)) or row.Value < (median - (1.5* iq_range)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
#apply the function to the original df:
df.loc[:, 'outlier'] = df.apply(is_outlier, axis = 1)
#filter to only non-outliers:
df_no_outliers = df[~(df.outlier)]
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, this is what I was looking for. Can you please suggest a good tutorial on Pandas. I am a beginner and have not much experience. Cheers!

Comment: can you please explain this part of code: statBefore.loc[row.ID]['q3']

Comment: @user1584253 This function returns the respective quantile with regard to individual features.

Answer (score 1):

```
Q1 = df['Value'].quantile(0.25)
Q3 = df['Value'].quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1

data = df[~((df['Value'] < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(df['Value'] > (Q3 + 1.5 * 
IQR))).any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

just do :

```
In [187]: df[df<100].groupby('ID').agg(['mean','median','std'])
Out[187]: 
   Value                  
    mean median        std
ID                        
A   75.0   75.0   7.071068
B   62.5   62.5  17.677670
C   35.0   35.0  35.355339
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like to remove outliers first, before doing mean, std calculations. The outlier method I would like to use is the one used by Boxplot calculations

Comment: I don't know this method. have you references ?