# Removing outlier from time series analysis using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, cross-validation

I have a time series analysis to model NDVI.
I used the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series
from matplotlib import pyplot
series = Series.from_csv('WSC-10-50.csv', header=0)
pyplot.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
pyplot.plot(series)
pyplot.show()

print(series.describe())
```

How do I remove any outliers from the data set and replot?
I would also like to run the best fit line across new plot with the outliers removed

Any help?

Comment: The question is too broad. Consider asking it on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=outliers); you may have a better response rate.

Comment: ... or narrowing down to an actual question.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686720/is-there-a-numpy-builtin-to-reject-outliers-from-a-list).