# Iterate through a generator object in Python

Tags: python, generator

I have some code in Python which connects to SQL Server and returns a crosstab of data using `pyodbc`.

I then perform some statistical analysis on that data row by row, as each row contains statistical data unique to a vendor.  I've got most of the code working just fine, can iterate through each column in each row and return lots of useful statistical analysis.  I've also got `matplotlib` working, creating a scatter plot and drawing an OLS regression line over the data.  The last piece of this script I need is to get the outliers, which I get using the following:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

results = sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(x)).fit()
test = results.outlier_test()
```

The `test` data look like this:

```
[[ -1.66666636e-01   8.70954193e-01   1.00000000e+00]
[  1.85524023e-01   8.56527067e-01   1.00000000e+00]
[ -5.07693609e-01   6.22677469e-01   1.00000000e+00]
[ -5.22476578e-01   6.12716252e-01   1.00000000e+00]
[ -5.40267858e-01   6.00836859e-01   1.00000000e+00]
[ -5.61134260e-01   5.87059066e-01   1.00000000e+00]
[  1.11050592e+01   6.03423147e-07   7.84450092e-06]
[  1.97665390e-01   8.47267021e-01   1.00000000e+00]
[ -3.10806108e-01   7.62329771e-01   1.00000000e+00]
[ -2.02176433e-01   8.43832634e-01   1.00000000e+00]
[  4.36313403e-02   9.66057205e-01   1.00000000e+00]
[ -2.89236184e-01   7.78308296e-01   1.00000000e+00]
[ -5.49558759e-01   5.94681341e-01   1.00000000e+00]]
```

To iterate through this and determine outliers in these data:

```
outliers = ([x[i],y[i]] for i,t in enumerate(test) if t[2] < 0.5)
```

This runs in a `for` loop, `for row in rows` where `rows` are the rows returned from the SQL query.  So I'm performing this outlier test on each row of data, to find which data points are potential outliers from that particular result set (the crosstab is actually a calculated result set pulled from another query, but that's not important here).  This `test` output is for one `row` from data.

In some cases, there are multiple outliers in the data.  However, I can't seem to find a way to iterate through each `outliers` object.  No matter what I try, I only get the first outlier result in `outliers`, even when there are multiple known outliers.  It's not a problem with the data because I've proven it through other methods, I just can't seem to iterate through the `outliers` generator object.

I'm fairly new to generator objects, but I have done some research on them.  I have a decent understanding of how they work, but even code that I thought was working, wasn't.

Using something like

```
for i in outliers:
    print i
```

I only get the first outlier in the list:  `[6, 136.84]`  -- (In the example data given above, this  the only outlier but as stated elsewhere in this question, even when there are known multiple outliers only the first one in the set is returned)

Using

```
for i in list(outliers):
    print i
```

gives me the same results.

Using

```
for i in list(next(outliers)):
    print i
```

results in returning the two values, `x` and `y` on separate lines, as if iterating through the sublist `[x, y]` rather than the `outliers` generator.

The last thing I've tried is various permutations of this

```
try:
    for i in next(outliers):
        print list(next(outliers))
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

I'll note that this particular code doesn't actually print *anything*.

I've also tried

```
try:
    if next(outliers, None) != None:
        print list(outliers)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

which results in

```
[]
```

I had something working yesterday but for some reason it was skipping some results and I couldn't figure out why.  Unfortunately, I lost that code and now I'm back at square one unable to make any further progress.

EDIT:

Here is a `test` data set which contains multiple outliers:

```
[[-1.06904497  0.31017523  1.        ]
[        inf  0.          0.        ]
[-0.74947341  0.47083534  1.        ]
[-0.61974867  0.54928322  1.        ]
[-0.50178907  0.62667871  1.        ]
[-0.3917734   0.70344466  1.        ]
[-0.28680336  0.78011746  1.        ]
[-0.18448201  0.85732288  1.        ]
[-0.08262629  0.93577921  1.        ]
[ 0.02097215  0.98368044  1.        ]
[ 0.12880164  0.90006829  1.        ]
[ 0.24397502  0.8121827   1.        ]
[ 0.37079182  0.71852659  1.        ]]
```

EDIT OF THE EDIT:

This question can be closed.  I must have been getting false positives on which data points were outliers yesterday, which resulted in my thinking the generator iteration wasn't working when I was only getting one result today.  After using some test data which for certain contains outliers, my generator iteration is working correctly.

Comment: I think you need `outliers = [...]` instead of `outliers = (...)`.

Comment: Even using `outliers = [...]`, it still only returns the first `[x,y]` pairing in `outliers`, rather than every `[x,y]` pairing generated.

Comment: Oops, nevermind. I didn't know `(...)` created a generator.

Comment: What did you expect from `next`? Next returns the following element in the iteration. `outliers` produces 2-element tuples so `next` returns *one* 2-element tuple, the call to `list` transforms the tuple into a list of two elements and you are iterating over it. I really have no idea why you add a call to `next` if you want to iterate over the whole generator.

Comment: Hi Bakuriu, I guess that illustrates my limited understanding of generators, or I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the logic.  What would you suggest?

Comment: in `test`, there is only one line that matches `t[2] > 05`, that's `[  1.11050592e+01   6.03423147e-07   7.84450092e-06]`. Therefore outliers contains only 1 element (all the others have `t[2] == 1`)

Comment: njzk2, I know this -- the `test` data given in the example does not contain multiple outliers, however I do have other data that does.  Let me add that to the post.

Comment: Your first loop is the right way to iterate over a generator. Your problem suggests that you have an error in the generator expression itself. Could you provide some test data with multiple known outliers where this still only gives one?

Comment: @lvc: Added a `test` set which I believe contains multiple outliers.

Comment: @devOpsEv that data still only has one row that matches t[2] < 0.5, which is row 1, `[inf 0. 0.]` - all other rows have t[2] being 1, which is bigger than 0.5. Are you sure that t[2] < 0.5 is the right test?

Comment: do `print list(outliers)` in a case where there is more than 1 outlier.

Comment: @lvc, Based on this, [Can scipy.stats identify and mask obvious outliers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231206/can-scipy-stats-identify-and-mask-obvious-outliers), which is where I got the code to create the generator, yes.  Perhaps I was mistaken about that data set.  I'm working with 8 or 9 different sets, and I can't recall which one passed the "multiple outliers" test.

Comment: Now I'm not certain about my data.  Running a test against `test` where I force a few outliers, I get printed results for each outlier.  I must have been doing something to my data yesterday to cause false positives on the outliers that I have since undone.  Back to the drawing board...  Thanks for the comments, everyone.  At least this question served as a good sanity check for myself.