# How to find the outlier (40, 10) in this case using IQR rule?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, data-science

Suppose I need to remove the outlier, that is (40, 10) in this case (refer to the plot attached below) using IQR rule, how do I do that?

Compared to the neighbouring points, (40, 10) is definitely an outlier. However,

Q1 = 11.25,

Q3 = 35.75

1.5 * IQR = 1.5 * (Q3 - Q1) = 36.75

Only points with y-val lower than 11.25-36.75 or greater than 35.75+36.75 are considered outliers.

How do I find and remove (40, 10) using IQR rule if I must use IQR rule?

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(50), 'y': [i if i != 40 else 10 for i in range(50)]})

plt.figure(**FIGURE)
plt.scatter(test['x'], test['y'], marker='x')
plt.show()
```

Here's the plot generated from the above code.

[image: plot]

Comment: You are using a 1D test for a 2D problem. You could create a regression line and use the distance to the regression line to identify outliers. See e.g. [Can scipy.stats identify and mask obvious outliers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231206/can-scipy-stats-identify-and-mask-obvious-outliers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are using the IQR is only considering the X axis component. If you do not include the Y axis components, then the point at (40, 10) is not an outlier.

You should use a method that considers 2D instances, such as [Local Outlier Factor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.LocalOutlierFactor.html) or any other.